# Disable Sonoma Video Screensaver

Tags: video, memory, screensaver, screen-lock

After updating to Sonoma, I turned on the new video screensaver. Now I would like to turn it off because I don't like it, but I can't seem to make it go away. I changed the Lock Screen settings to "Never" turn on the screensaver, but it still appears. My main question is simply how to make the video screensaver go away, or only show a static image.

One reason I want to turn it off is that it seems to use considerable memory and degrade performance of various background processes. I did not notice this degradation when the Lock Screen was on before upgrading to Sonoma. If you think the performance degradation is not caused by the screensaver, please give suggestions on how to preserve performance when the Lock Screen is on in Sonoma.

EDIT: What I am seeing might not be the screensaver, but a video autoplays on the lock screen. It also seems to be there when I return after the display has been turned off. I changed the wallpaper to a static image (not the screensaver). I will see if that improves the memory and perf issues.

Comment: How exactly are you checking the memory usage and performance of background processes, while the screen is locked and you can't see what's going on? Screen Saver selection is on a different settings panel, where you can select a static image.

Comment: Change the ScreenSaver to something else?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I am able to see memory usage by remotely logging into it. You made me realise that what I am seeing is not the screensaver, but the video plays during the lockscreen. I would like the background but I would like no video to play on the lockscreen.

Comment: I changed the wallpaper to a static image and will see if that improves the situation.

Comment: Changing the wallpaper to a static image instead of the video background fixed the issue. There is a 10x speedup of the background processes in some cases. The slowdown seems to be due to memory pressure from the wallpaper.